# Google ID-Token checker for Java check() return null

Tags: java, android, google-oauth, google-openid

I followed the blog post Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps (http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) to verify tokens sent by Android clients in Java.

I use the sample code in the blog post with Google Client Library for Java (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc.zip&can=2&q=).

However, the `GoogleIdToken.Payload check(String tokenString)` method in the sample code returns null sometimes. It is very annoying because I would like to use payload.getAudience() and payload.getAuthorizedParty() to prevent from spoofing. If the Payload is null, NullPointerException occurs.

How can we solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a try/catch and have checked you’re not getting an exception from the verify() call?

Assuming that, returning null means it failed to verify.  Reasons this could occur include:

- you're offline; the code can't fetch the Google cert to check the signature
- the token has expired; their lifetime is typically only an hour
- somehow the token has been changed so the signature no longer is valid

If you have a token that you are REALLY SURE should be valid, but the verify() call still returns null, then file a bug.

Comment: I am sorry that I do not understand about the try/catch assumption. I use the following code to use the Checker class in the sample code: 
 Checker checker = new Checker(new String[]{clientID},audience);
     Payload payload = checker.check(token);
     System.out.println(payload.getAudience()); //NPE
Should I surround these code with try/catch?

Comment: You might want to try this.  Hit https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<your-token-here> and see if your token is valid. If it is, but check() still returns null, definitely a bug

Comment: After trying, I find that I pass an incorrect client ID into Checker. The token is valid but check() returns null because I pass an incorrect clientID. Is it working as intended or is it a bug? If it is working as intended, I hope it can give more specific message.

Comment: Is the url in the form https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123 or https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=XYZ123? In the document at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login, it says the former form.

Comment: It depends whether you want to look at an Access Token or an ID Token.  The docs for the APIs you’re using should make it pretty clear which of those you’re dealing with at any point in time.

Comment: @TimBray Since today morning, i am getting null when calling tempPayload.getIssuee() in my server code. Token sent from android device is valid. Code Ref: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html Jar: google-api-client 1.14.1-beta. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case null was caused by the [issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/pull/976) inside the library. 
Description: The issuer was 'accounts.google.com' but in response I had 'https://accounts.google.com'.
Solution: I had manually changed the issuer and that helps.

P.S.
The issue is already fixed but it's still not included in the release version, at least at the moment of my answer.